# Data gets updated every-time user logs into Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to login a user & check if a user is new or not & if he/she is new give that particular user 1000 coins, however every time the user logs out & logs in even if they aren't new (they already exist in my database) the user's coins change to 1000, am I doing something wrong?

```
int coins = 1000;

 Future<GoogleSignInAccount> _handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser =
          (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('u')
            .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
            .getDocuments();
        final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
        if (documents.length == 0) {
          // Update data to server if new user
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('u')
              .document(firebaseUser.uid)
              .setData({
            'coins': coins,
          });
        }
      }
      return googleUser;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between your query and the way you store your data.

You store you data as:

```
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('u')
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .setData({
    'coins': coins,
  });
```

So each user is stored in a document that has their UID as the key, and that has a single field called `coins`.

Then when you try to load this document, you do:

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('u')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
    .getDocuments();
```

This query looks for documents that have **a field `id`** with the value of the user's UID. And since your documents only contain a `coins` field, there is no document that matches this query.

The solution is to use a direct lookup of the user's document, instead of a query:

```
final DocumentSnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('u')
    .document(firebaseUser.uid)
    .get();
if (!documents.exists) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot